# How to retrieve all airports around a given osm-ID

Tags: overpass-api

I want to retrieve all airports around a city (g.e. Leipzig) within a radius of 50km.

I tried this

```
[out:csv(::type,name, 'name', ::id; true; ";")];
(
  relation["iata"~".*"](around: 50000, 51.3124404, 12.4131075);
  node["iata"~".*"](around: 50000, 51.3124404, 12.4131075);
  way["iata"~".*"](around: 50000, 51.3124404, 12.4131075);
);
out;
```

returns

```
@type;name;name;@id
way;Flughafen Leipzig/Halle;Flughafen Leipzig/Halle;435715317
relation;Leipzig-Altenburg Airport;Leipzig-Altenburg Airport;6116338
```

But I want to use the osm-id directly.

When I search within Leipzig (admin_level = 8) and a radius

```
[out:csv(::type,name, 'name', ::id; true; ";")];
area(3600062649) -> .leipzig;
way(around.leipzig:50000)[iata~".*"]({{bbox}});
out;
```

I retrieve an empty result set

When I search within saxony (admin_level = 4)

```
area(3600062467) -> .sachsen;
way(area.sachsen)[iata~".*"]({{bbox}});
out;
```

then I retrieve

```
@type;name;name;@id
way;Flughafen Leipzig/Halle;Flughafen Leipzig/Halle;435715317
```

I want to retrieve the same result like I use the lat/lon-information.

Edit: 
I get the expected result by retriving the center-lat/lon of a relation (given by an osm-id) and use this lat/lon-information to retrieve all airports within a given radius.

Now I want to skip the step "retrieve center-lat/lon". I want to use the osm-id of a relation and a given radius directly to retrieve all airports within a given radius.

@mmd: I hope it's more understandable.

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, at one point you say " want to use the osm-id directly", and later "like I use the lat/lon-information" - both of which are totally different things. Can you edit your question, what exactly you want your query to be based on, best with an example of an "OSM id" you want to use. By the way, you cannot use (around:...) with areas, it only supports nodes, ways and relations in the inputset.

Comment: Usually, you would query all airports in the area enclosed by a relation. is this what you want? Querying airports which are within a given radius of a relation doesn't make really that much sense in most cases, as you would only consider the boundary way itself. If there's an airport right in the center of a relation, which is too far away from the relation boundary, you wouldn't see that airport in your results.

Comment: How does it work. For example the Airport LEJ (Halle/Leipzig in Saxony) is close to Halle (Saxony-Anhalt) and Leipzig (Saxony). When I start to search airports close to Leipzig - then I have to use Saxony. In this case, I'm able to find the airport. When I search for airports close to Halle (Saale) then I would use Saxony-Anhalt - and could not find this airport. And the next level s germany and this is not very helpful.

Is it an idea to use a buffer around the relation and then search within the buffered relation for airports?